# Python C Extensions adding Attributes to an Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

I'm wrapping a C library which returns one of a finite number of error codes upon failure. When the error happens, I would like to add the error code as an attribute on the C exception, such that the Python code can retrieve it and map the error code to a human readable exception. Is this possible?

For example I want to do this in the Python layer:

```
try:
    call_my_library_func()
except MyLibraryError as ex:
    print("Error code was %s" % ex.code)
```

The closest I can get to, which I don't like, is by using `PyErr_SetObject`

```
PyObject *tuple = PyTuple_New(2);
PyTuple_SetItem(tuple, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("Helpful error message"));
PyTuple_SetItem(tuple, 1, PyLong_FromLong(257));
//PyErr_SetString(MyLibraryError, "Helpful error message\n");
PyErr_SetObject(MyLibraryError, tuple);
```

Then I can do this:

```
try:
    call_my_library_func()
except MyLibraryError as ex:
    message, code = ex.args[0], -1
    if len(ex.args > 1):
        code = ex.args[1]
```

Comment: Could you define the class `MyLibraryError` so that `MyLibraryError.code` is a property that returns `args[1]`?

Comment: @DavidW Currently `MyLibraryError` in this example is an exception defined in C. Do you suggest creating a Python Exception which subclasses this C exception, like `class MyPyLibraryError(LibraryError) @property def code() return getattr(self, 'code', -1)` ?

Comment: I was suggesting `class MyPyLibraryError(LibraryError) @property def code(self): return self.args[1] if len(self.args)>=2 else -1`. If `MyLibraryError` is a class you've made then can create the property in C instead of making a Python subclass.

Comment: @DavidW Great, and then in Python I would do `try: call_my_library_func() except MyLibraryError as ex: raise MyPyLibraryError(*ex.args)` right -- and better yet add it as a decorator and apply it to all my my functions?

Comment: Not quite - in C you raise the `MyPyLibraryError` (using the tuple, like you're doing). In Python you just do `try: call_my_library_func() except MyPyLibraryError as ex: code = ex.code # ... and whatever else you want`

Comment: I'll try to make a quick example.... It's probably clearer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C API exception handling is largely written in terms of raising an exception by its class, its arguments (passed to the constructor) and its traceback, and therefore those it's probably best to follow that scheme. Your basic approach of passing a tuple as the arguments is probably the best option.

However there are two options to make your exception class slightly more user-friendly on the Python side:

1. You process the arguments in a custom `__init__` method to set a `code` attribute on the class.
2. You define `code` as a property of your exception class that accesses `args[1]`.

I've illustrated option 2, but I don't think there a huge reason to prefer one or the other.

---

To briefly explain the example code below: to define an exception using the C API you use `PyErr_NewException` which takes an optional base class and dictionary as its second and third arguments. The functions used (either `__init__` or the property definitions) should be part of the dictionary.

To define the property definitions I've written the code in Python and used `PyRun_String` since it's easier to write in Python than C and because I doubt this code will be performance critical. The functions end up injected into the global dictionary passed to `PyRun_String`.

C code:

```c
#include <Python.h>

PyObject* make_getter_code() {
    const char* code = 
    "def code(self):\n"
    "  try:\n"
    "    return self.args[1]\n"
    "  except IndexError:\n"
    "    return -1\n"
    "code = property(code)\n"
    "def message(self):\n"
    "  try:\n"
    "    return self.args[0]\n"
    "  except IndexError:\n"
    "    return ''\n"
    "\n";

    PyObject* d = PyDict_New();
    PyObject* dict_globals = PyDict_New();
    PyDict_SetItemString(dict_globals, "__builtins__", PyEval_GetBuiltins());
    PyObject* output = PyRun_String(code,Py_file_input,dict_globals,d);
    if (output==NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(d);
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_DECREF(output);
    Py_DECREF(dict_globals);
    return d;
}

static PyObject* MyLibraryError;

static PyObject* my_library_function(PyObject* self) {
    /* something's gone wrong */
    PyObject *tuple = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SetItem(tuple, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("Helpful error message"));
    PyTuple_SetItem(tuple, 1, PyLong_FromLong(257));
    PyErr_SetObject(MyLibraryError, tuple);
    return NULL;
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"my_library_function",  my_library_function,  METH_NOARGS,
     "raise an error."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

static struct PyModuleDef librarymodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "library",   /* name of module */
    NULL, /* module documentation, may be NULL */
    -1,       /* size of per-interpreter state of the module,
                 or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables. */
    methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_library(void) {
    PyObject *m;
    m = PyModule_Create(&librarymodule);
    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;

    PyObject* exc_dict = make_getter_code();
    if (exc_dict == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    MyLibraryError = PyErr_NewException("library.MyLibraryError", 
                                        NULL, // use to pick base class
                                        exc_dict);
    PyModule_AddObject(m,"MyLibraryError",MyLibraryError);
    return m;
}
```

As an example of the more elegant Python interface, your Python code changes to:

```
try:
    my_library_func()
except MyLibraryError as ex:
    message, code = ex.message, ex.code
```

Comment: Very cool. I did not know about `PyRun_String` or setting the dict during `PyErr_NewException`. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an edit that shows how you can directly do what you original asked about (set an attribute on the current exception) an therefore avoid messing around with custom classes. I'd personally still use the custom class though

Comment: Regarding your addendum, I had to do `PyObject_SetAttrString(type, ...)`, not `value`. Using `value` raised an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'err'`. Additionally, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html) have this warning about `PyErr_Restore`: "If you don’t understand this, don’t use this function. I warned you." - so I'll think I'll implement your first suggestion :)

Comment: In your first suggestion, why are you doing the `PyDict_DelItemString(dict, "__builtins__")` ? I noticed that I cannot use `len` for example in my `code` block, but if I comment out the `PyDict_DelItemString` line, I can then use `len`.

Comment: You're right - I don't seem to be able to get the addendum to work. I can't remember at this stage if I actually had it working, or was just "certain" it would work... I've removed it anyway. Sorry about that!

Comment: About `PyDict_DelItemString(dict, "__builtins__")` - I'm doing it mostly because I don't want `__builtins__` to be an attribute. That's OK with `property` which is evaluated during `PyRun_String`, but not for code that's actually in your functions (which is evaluated later). Remove the `PyDict_DelItemString` if you want...

Comment: However what you should really do is pass a separate locals and globals argument to `PyRun_String`, with builtins in the globals. I've updated the answer to show that. Sorry - doesn't look like the original version was as good as it could have been

Comment: Cool thanks. On an unrelated note, ignoring performance, can you think of an example when it would be better to write a C Extension instead of using cffi/ctypes? I spent this weekend doing a POC with cffi/ctypes and now I'm wondering if should trash my C extension and replace it. I don't have any particular performance need like a tight loop (and my understanding is that a call to a cffi/ctypes function will release the GIL).

Comment: @MatthewMoisen It's easier to hide implementation details from users of your Python library in C API. With ctypes your uses can always start digging around and manipulating the pointer types. Other than that it's often a good option - I believe the people at PyPy created CFFI with the expectation that most "wrapper" C API extensions could be written in CFFI so you should be able to accomplish what you want.